# why is boost::circular_buffer so slow in my benchmark?

Tags: c++, boost

Reading the [rationale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/circular_buffer/rationale.html), boost::circular_buffer looked promising:

> Suitability for real-time and performance critical applications.
>
> Fast constant-time insertion and removal of elements from the front and back.

When I run a simple benchmark that simulates my use case, using it as a byte buffer:

1. write a bigger chunk
2. read smaller chunks until empty
3. repeat

the performance is absolutely abysmal, more than [4000x](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72382381b2b1c931) slower than my own hack and spsc_queue.

```
lin : 101  // 10240x
lock: 109  // 10240x
circ: 427  // 10x
```

Note that the loopcount for `circular` is `10` and the loopcount for the others is `10*1024`. See working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bff5f0ec07a20ac).

Am I using it completely wrong or was it just not designed with fundamental / POD types in mind?

**Edit:**

Adopting the benchmark with the provided changes does not fully resolve the issues on MSVC2015. There a factor of 100x remains.

```
lin : 69   // 10240x
lock: 79   // 10240x
circ: 9688 // 10240x
```

Inserting several items at once being so slow is problematic. Assigning would work in this special scenario because the buffer is depleted before the insert, but this is not a general solution. In resume spsc_queue wins on all fronts, its fast, can be used without depletion, and can be used in a mulithreaded environment (in a single producer single consumer scenario).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, make sure the benchmarks are sound. If you don't use the results of the computations, compilers will eliminate it as dead code when you least expect it.

0. You circular deletion looks suboptimal. Use this instead:

   ```
   buffer.erase_begin(1024); // or indeed, use checked size see below
   ```

   > **UPDATE**
1. The second thing that was hurting performance - badly - was the `insert` call. In your use-case you can use `assign` which, like in the contenders, gets compiled down to a memcpy or memmove.
2. Make sure debugging is disabled (define `NDEBUG` and or `BOOST_CB_DISABLE_DEBUG`)

Here's my refactored benchmark using [Nonius](https://github.com/rmartinho/nonius): http://paste.ubuntu.com/15222217/

clock resolution: mean is 18.6412 ns (40960002 iterations)

```
benchmarking linear
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 3.93727 s
mean: 39.0804 ms, lb 39.0567 ms, ub 39.1051 ms, ci 0.95
std dev: 124.19 μs, lb 111.153 μs, ub 141.079 μs, ci 0.95
found 0 outliers among 100 samples (0%)
variance is unaffected by outliers

benchmarking lockfree
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 4.78513 s
mean: 37.0188 ms, lb 37.0106 ms, ub 37.0277 ms, ci 0.95
std dev: 43.5788 μs, lb 37.3685 μs, ub 52.8458 μs, ci 0.95
found 3 outliers among 100 samples (3%)
variance is unaffected by outliers

benchmarking circular
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 9.78763 s
mean: 62.884 ms, lb 62.8657 ms, ub 62.9041 ms, ci 0.95
std dev: 98.0325 μs, lb 85.6543 μs, ub 119.395 μs, ci 0.95
found 1 outliers among 100 samples (1%)
variance is unaffected by outliers
```

Interactive results: http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/57c2bfea-3e9d-4503-8d23-3b88209fc3ce/stats.html

[image]

Without nonius: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff17d470044332f8)</kbd>**

Output

```
lin : 101 (checksum: -1741910392)
lock: 89 (checksum: -1741910392)
circ: 102 (checksum: -1741910392)
```

Comment: Hmpf. After making sure the iterations are the same across benchmarks (!) there is still a largish gap. Looking for more clues

Comment: The times were changing linear with amount of data so I was fairly sure the optimizer wasn't causing the surprising result, but yes, normaly I make sure I use the result.

Comment: Good point. Nevertheless, better be explicit. Another good thing to look at is `-DNDEBUG` or `-DBOOST_CB_DISABLE_DEBUG` maybe. I see `debug.hpp` a lot in the profiling data

Comment: had problems compiling your changes. MSVC 2015 chokes on `std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t>` which is apparently correct `The effect is undefined if this is not one of short, int, long, long long, unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, or unsigned long long.`

Comment: Just make it `uniform_int_distribution<int>` - for this purpose it doesn't matter. I think you're right that char is not a proper T for uniform_int_distribution (I forgot)

Comment: Already did. Also moved the generator & accumulate out of the benchmarks because I want the time just for the buffer ops.

Comment: Just updated my answer with a breakthrough other improvement. I'm going to make the benchmark statistically more informed now.

Comment: Updated the benchmark to use Nonius. Note that on Coliru, the `circular` buffer ran ~as quick as the `linear` version. That could be a fluke, which is why I prefer to use a Nonius which does more measurements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104753/discussion-between-thomas-and-sehe).